# How many rows will we draw in Hasse diagram?

Tags: combinatorics

Hi i have a finite group in a size of N and i need to know how many lines can i draw based on N in a Hasse diagram(ordered by inclusion like in the examples).

In the first example(N=3) we have 12 lines and in the other example we have 4 lines (N=2).

How many lines for N=35 for example? how can i know the number of lines i can draw based on the size of my group(N)?

[image: for example here (N=3) we have 12 lines:]
[image: and here (N=2) we have 4 lines:]

Answer (score 3):

For a [complete lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice) of size $N$ its [height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain#Height_and_width) can be anything from $2$ (incomparable elements with $\bot$ and $\top$)

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&\top \\
\nearrow&\uparrow&\ldots&\nwarrow\\
\bullet\hspace{17pt}&\bullet& \ldots &\hspace{18pt}\bullet \\
\nwarrow&\uparrow&\ldots&\nearrow\\
&\bot
\end{array}
$$

to $N-1$ (linear order)

$$\bot \to \bullet\to \bullet\to\ldots\to \bullet \to \top.$$

On the other hand, the [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of the lattice of [all the subsets of some set $A$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) forms a [hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube), hence has

- $2^{|A|}$ vertices,
- $\frac{1}{2}|A|2^{|A|}$ edges,
- height $|A|$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

What you called a group is more commonly called a set. The Hasse diagram of subsets of a finite set is a [hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube), the number of arrows in the Hasse diagram is the number of edges oh the hypercube, which is $2^{N-1}N$.

Comment: Thanks English is not my native language so i tried to translate how they call it in my language to English :)

Comment: 'Group' would be a reasonable word to choose in non-technical English, but in math there is a big difference between 'set' and 'group', so it's good to learn the distinction, @kfir.